# Web Essentials Less on imported file save does not compile main file

Tags: compiler-construction, less, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I have the latest build of Web Essentials 2013 (1.4.1). On the official page of [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog) they say that in 2013 version fixed that issue:

> **1.4 - December 1, 2013**
>   LESS/CoffeeScript Various bug fixes and perf improvements
>
> **1.3 - November 16, 2013**
>   LESS compiler now runs in NodeJS Bootstrap class name validator
>
> **1.2 - November 4, 2013**
>   LESS relative paths fix Various fixes and tweaks

but when I change and save imported file in Visual Studio, it does not update main CSS file anymore. It needs to save the host less file to make changes in CSS.

There is a screenshot of my options:
[image: Web Essentials LESS options]

Comment: But did they say they fixed exactly that issue? I see only they state that *some* LESS related bugs are fixed.

Comment: They said so :( anyways this issue is really actual for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the options check the Unused CSS settings. make sure the imported filename pattern is not in the list. the default is bootstrap*; reset.css; normalize.css; jquery*; toastr*; foundation*; animate*; inuit*; elements*; ratchet*; hint*; flat-ui*; 960*; skeleton*